# Slight transparent space between two divs

Tags: html, css

I have two div's above one another. The top div has a background .svg at the bottom with the same color as the background of the bottom div. These should align perfectly, however, they do not. There is an ever so slight amount of transparent space between them. This space disappears when zooming in and reappears when zooming in even further (see screenshots).

```css
.top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #3772ff;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22100%25%22%20height%3D%22100%25%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20378%20378%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M0%2C378l378%2C-0l-0%2C-47.25l-378%2C47.25Z%22%20style%3D%22fill%3A%2301161e%3B%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left bottom;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: #01161e;
  padding: 128px 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

Screenshots:

100% zoom:

[image: 100% zoom]

A bit zoomed in:

[image: a bit zoomed in]

Zooming in even further:

[image: zooming in even further]

Comment: @charmander Which browser are you rendering this in?

Comment: @Martin google chrome, edit: edge has the same issue

Comment: @isherwood I've added the svg to the snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a more elegant solution to be had, but simply pulling the lower element up a fraction of a pixel overcomes the sub-pixel rounding issue.

```css
.top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #3772ff;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22100%25%22%20height%3D%22100%25%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20378%20378%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M0%2C378l378%2C-0l-0%2C-47.25l-378%2C47.25Z%22%20style%3D%22fill%3A%2301161e%3B%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left bottom;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: #01161e;
  padding: 128px 20%;
  margin-top: -.5px;
  /* transform: translateY(-.5px); alternative approach */
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

Of course, you could just set the body background (or that of a container element) to hide it as well:

```css
.container {
  background-color: #01161e;
}

.top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #3772ff;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22100%25%22%20height%3D%22100%25%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20378%20378%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M0%2C378l378%2C-0l-0%2C-47.25l-378%2C47.25Z%22%20style%3D%22fill%3A%2301161e%3B%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left bottom;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: #01161e;
  padding: 128px 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```